# how to add a fixed image in an editable tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a editable table i use

> for change my table as editable .now i want to add a image or a content(text) "+" inside the tr which is not editable

```js
  $('#tabledata').editableTableWidget();//for editable

 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html("<button class=collapsebutton>-</button> " + OriginalContent + " ");// for adding a button
```

i use code like this but now the button was removable(editing time) iwant that button as fixed one not an edited one

Comment: Can you please give us a working code/fiddle link.. Partial code won't help us to resolve any issue.